# JavaScript - saving highlighted rows

Tags: javascript, html

Below is script to highlight rows in html file:

```
$(function(){
    $('table').addClass("table table-bordered table-condensed");
    $('.table').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
        var $tr = $(this);

        var $table = $tr.closest('.table');
        var our_index = $($tr,$table).index();
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var last_index = $table.data('last-index');
            if (last_index) {
                if (last_index < our_index) {
                    while(last_index < our_index) {
                        $('tbody tr:eq('+(++last_index)+')', $table).click();
                    }   
                    $('tbody tr:eq('+(last_index)+')', $table).click();
                } else {  
                    while(last_index > our_index) {
                        $('tbody tr:eq('+(--last_index)+')', $table).click();
                    }
                    $('tbody tr:eq('+(last_index)+')', $table).click();
                } 
            }
            $table.data('last-index',our_index);
        } else {
            $table.data('last-index',our_index);
        }

        if ($tr.hasClass('success')) {
            $tr.removeClass('success');
        } else {
            $tr.addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

I'd like now to save those highlighted rows so that when someone else will open the page, rows highlighted by be will be visible and if I will highlight some cells and then refresh the page they will stay highlighted.

Is there any simple way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

-----EDIT-----

I was trying to do it via localStorage:

```
$('tr').each(function(index){

if(localStorage.getItem(index)!=null){
    $(this).addClass(localStorage.getItem(index));
}
});
```

and part to save:

```
if ($tr.hasClass('success')) {
            $tr.removeClass('success');
        } else {
            $tr.addClass('success');
            $tr.localStorage.setItem(index, 'success');
        }
```

But, that's not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Sorry if my questions are obvious, but I'm starting with web programming.

Comment: Try [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) - you will need to store the changes on the server and have the server add the classes to the rows/cells before loading

Comment: @GeorgeJempty why on earth not? Just update the table on the server with the classes

Comment: I *think* `$tr.localStorage.setItem(index, 'success')` should be just `localStorage.setItem(index, 'success')`. You need to get the index value from the row (our_index maybe)

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot!

Comment: @mplungjan Are there any server side technologies listed in the tags?  I didn't think so

Comment: But this works only for one user, highlighted cells are not shared with other users. Is there any modification of it to save it into the folder with whole project?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Did OP know what to tag at the time of asking? I didn't think so. My comment was _you will need to store the changes on the_ ***server*** _and have the server add the classes to the rows/cells before loading_

Comment: Google docs can do it.

Comment: Sure.. However "No not possible" should likely have been "No not possible client side only" - you were already assuming the tags posted were cast in stone. Anyway. I think OP gets the drift from the comments so far.

Answer (score 0):

To condense the comments and try to come up with answers:

1. You cannot client-side store any information that is available to other users on another computer. You will need some kind of server
2. When you attempt collaborative editing, you need to handle concurrency or ignore it, so whoever gets to the server first, get their version saved

To communicate with the server, you can use Ajax. NOTE this code was not tested:

```
var rows = [], saveRows = [];
function saveState() {
  $('tbody tr').each() {
    if ($(this).is(".success")) rows.push($(this).index())
  }
  if (rows.join(",") != saveRows.join(",")) {
    saveRows = rows.slice(0); // copy;
    $.post("storeRows.php",{"rows":rows.length>0?rows.join(","):""},function(res) {
      console.log("stored");
      if (res.rows.join(",") != saveRows.join(",")) {
         $('tbody tr').each(function(i) {
           $(this).toggleclass("success",rows.indexOf(i));
         });
      }
    });
  }
 }
 setInterval(saveState,3000);
```

The server needs to save the list somewhere

```
1,4,7,9
```

and then use it to initialise the table when making it OR have the ajax do the job when loading the table.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I've got one additional question. I'm republishing the page via saving excel file and I would like to reset all highlighted data while republishing, but I don't know how to check if the page was refreshed. Any ideas?

Comment: Saving Excel file how? And serving it how? The server process could read the file date and send it along with the data. Then you could inquire from the client if there was a new file by asking the server to look at the file date

Comment: I was talking about localStorage. I've my data in excel and refreshing the data in excel = refreshing the data on page. I want to capture the moment of saving new data to remove all highlighted cells.

Comment: You will still need to look at the server to get the file date.